# What do I have to do to use an external open source library in my Java project?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am a Java beginner and need help with using any external library in my Java application.

I have created a simple Java application that uses Swing. I am using Eclipse Java EE IDE (Mars 2).

I want to use [jwtk/jjwt](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt) in my Java project to create and verify Jason Web Tokens (JWT).

I see that every page lists Maven dependencies. I just don't know what to do with them. I don't think I am even using Maven and or may be I am but I don't quite understand what it is.

I know how to write code using the library. And I know what JWT's are and how to use them. The only help I need is with setting up the tools, i.e. once I have figured out what open source library I want to use, what do I do to get it into my Java application in Eclipse?

What are the steps I need to perform to use [jwtk/jjwt](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt) in my Java application?

Comment: Didn't the README file tell you already?

Comment: Nope. I read that first thing. It assumes you already know this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to use tooling like Maven or Gradle.

Here are the steps you will need to do , for maven

a) Download M2E or similar plugin for eclipse

b) You can install that from the Help->Updates in maven

c) Get a basic POM (there are a lot of examples as to how to do it , one way could be to use a maven starter in a new project dialog in eclipse)

d) Add dependencies for example , this library has this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
    <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
    <version>0.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

e) You can run lifecycle tasks on maven (clean , compile , install etc.) within eclipse.

You can as well add the jar on its own to the build path , the problems you will find could be ClassNotFound exceptions at runtime due to missing dependencies. These tools can save up quite a bit there.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you. I think I already have Maven installed. It comes with the Eclipse installation, I think. I am assuming I have it because when I create a new project, it shows up Maven and Gradle type project templates as well. I assume in steps (a) and (b) you're asking that I get Maven. Assuming I have it, I won't need (a) and (b), right? And then step (c) onwards, you lost me completely.

Comment: Yes that is right. Those steps are applicable for basic eclipse installs without Maven or Gradle support

Answer (score 1):

An external Java library is released as a jar file. To be able to use this jar file in your application, you need

- to add this jar in the classpath when building your app, because the compiler needs to have access to the class files it contains
- to add this jar in the classpath when running your app, because the runtime needs to have access to the class files it contains

But that's not sufficient though, because the library itself uses other libraries. So these libraries must also be available. Some at runtime only. Some at compile and runtime.

That's where tools like Maven and Gradle are useful (I would advise you to use Gradle): you simply tell them whhich library you depend on, and it automatically downloads this library, and its dependencies, and the dependencies of the dependencies, etc.. And it sets up the necessary environment to compile and run the app, and much more.

Eclipse, when using the right plugins (Buildship for gradle), allows just importing the gradle or Maven project, and sets up the Eclipse project automatically, allowing to use your IDE as you're used to do it.

For more information, read the documentation. Gradle's is top-notch. Maven's is... perfectible.

Comment: Thank you. I found your answer very helpful and I'll try and figure out the rest. But what if I don't have even the jar files? As in this case, there are only source files available.

Comment: gradle and maven will download the jar files for you, from the [maven central repository](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/jsonwebtoken/jjwt/0.6.0/). You could do all this by yourself, but there's a much bigger chance of screwing up.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your eclipse version already have a maven plugin.

To start using maven, simply create a new maven project.

The maven project has a standard folder structure, and coming with a pom.xml

Once you include a valid dependancy in the pom.xml and save, the build path will be updated automatically.

You can check the versions of the maven repository of json web token at below URL

[io.josnwebtoken](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt/0.1)